# Repeating qualifier is ignored in regex

Tags: python, regex, perl

I got stuck on building a regex with repeating qualifier. No luck finding a piece of advise online.

Here is a string to match -

```
abc cde fgi
```

The regex is

```
^(?:(.*?)(abc|fgi)){2}(.*)$
```

Here is example output from redemo.py:

[image: the way how the regex matches the string]

A similar output I am getting from the Perl:

```
perl --version | head -2; perl -MData::Dumper -e 'print Dumper ["abc cde fgi" =~ /^(?:(.*?)(abc|fgi)){2}(.*)$/g]'

This is perl 5, version 14, subversion 4 (v5.14.4) built for cygwin-thread-multi
$VAR1 = [
          ' cde ',
          'fgi',
          ''
        ];
```

I would better leave behind the scope the reason, why I have to apply exactly this regex.

But here is the problem: I would expect **'{2}' qualifier is a strict requirement** for matching the string, thus the interpreter will return 5 groups for successful match -

```
1: ''
2: 'abc'
3: ' '
4: 'fgi'
5: ''
```

Unexpectedly, the interpreter is fine with returning only 3 groups, it looks like '{2}' qualifier is being ignored.

Could someone comment if my understanding of regex repeating qualifiers is wrong?

Can anyone advise a tool to visualize how regex is being interpreted step-by-step?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've included the `{2}` in your regex, but you *haven't* included it in the matching group. That means that the repeat condition is evaluated when calculating whether there is a match, but it isn't evaluated when computing the groups that contributed to the match. Instead, you get *one* repetition of the group that matched twice. To get both repetitions assigned to the content of one group, include the `{2}` within the `()` for that group.

Note that you *never* get more groups assigned than there are pairs of literal `()` in the input. To get the individual repetitions of a group, you have to code a loop and repeat the match (or in Perl, include code in the regex via its `e` flag).

Comment: I understand your comment on creating a loop and must probably I will go that way. But could you explain what you mean by 'To get both repetitions assigned to the content of one group, include the {2} within the () for that group.' with some example?

Comment: If you match `([0-9]){3}`, then you will match if there is a three-digit number, but the return value will be only one of the digits (probably the last one). If you match `([0-9]{3})`, then the return value will be the entire three-digit number.